# read file name from directory

Tags: php, html

I want to read html file name from directory without any database. I have a code and its working properly, but two blank name it is giving, while I have only 4 file in directory.

```
<?php
 if (is_dir('dir')) {
if ($dh = opendir('dir')) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        echo "filename:".$file."<br />";
    }
}
}?>
```

I have 4 html file and output should be:

```
filename:aaaaaa kjnnk_13.html
filename:aaaaaa kjnnk_2.html
filename:aaaaaa kjnnk_6.html
filename:aaaaaa kjnnk_9.html
```

But I found 2 extra filename:

```
filename:.
filename:..
filename:aaaaaa kjnnk_13.html
filename:aaaaaa kjnnk_2.html
filename:aaaaaa kjnnk_6.html
filename:aaaaaa kjnnk_9.html
```

Please help

Comment: `if ($file != '.' && $file != '..')`

Comment: hank you for reply...But where add your condition?

Comment: Maybe before `echo`?

Comment: See the second example on the [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) documentation, this does exactly what you want. (The . and .. are two folder which represent the current directory and the parent directory).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

. is for current dir
.. is for one directory up

When using readdir you will get those 2 extra.

I prefer using glob(). That function lets you filter for html files only too

```
<?php
   $files = glob('dir/*html');
   foreach($files as $file) {
       echo "filename:".$file."<br />";
   }
?>
```

Comment: But if it will be php file then will be $files = glob('dir/*php')

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use [FilesystemIterator](http://php.net/FilesystemIterator) which would skip the dot files by default:

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator('dir');
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "<br/>";
}
```

more answers in stackoverflow:

[What exactly are the benefits of using a PHP 5 DirectoryIterator over PHP 4 "opendir/readdir/closedir"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775848/what-exactly-are-the-benefits-of-using-a-php-5-directoryiterator-over-php-4-ope)

[PHP: scandir() is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172784/php-scandir-is-too-slow)

[Difference between DirectoryIterator and FileSystemIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532064/difference-between-directoryiterator-and-filesystemiterator)